# Why is my memory usage increasing when I display the same UserControl again?

Tags: c#, memory, user-controls

I have a 2-pane C# application, a tree on the left, and a pane on the right. Clicking a tree node causes a custom UserControl to be displayed on the right.  I have several UC's in this app, depending on which tree node is clicked.
I am not doing any memory management when the user clicks a different tree node, what happens is that whatever UC is needed is loaded over the old one that was there.  I had thought C# handled memory management, however I am finding that if I continuously click one of my tree nodes, click away, and then click the same tree node again, memory usage keeps going up, every time the UC is loaded.  Clicking away does not release the memory.
There is no non-managed code here, however there is database access happening in Oracle on the UC, loading a DataGridView with records. 
What do I need to do to make the memory stop climbing every time I click on this tree node?
I am using Process Explorer to monitor the memory usage.  Its got up to over 1 GB before I stopped clicking.
Here is the code that loads the right hand pane(s).
Thanks.

```
private void LoadRightPane(TreeNode node)
    {
        splitPanelLeftRight.Panel2.Controls.Clear();

        try
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            // Need to create user control on GUI thread
            // But we still will load the various grids on the BW thread
            UserControl uc = null;
            IUap uap;
            INodeTag nodeTag = (INodeTag)node.Tag;
            bool result;
            result = _uapList.TryGetValue(nodeTag.AssemblyTypeName, out uap);
            if (result)
            {
                uc = uap.Create(node); // decides which user control to "new" (based on node info) and returns it
            }

            if (uc != null)
                _bw.RunWorkerAsync(uc);
            else
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Argument is IUapUserControl))
            throw new Exception("Exception: All user controls must implement the IUapUserControl interface.");
        IUapUserControl uc = e.Argument as IUapUserControl;
        uc.Populate(); // populates any info on UC
        e.Result = uc;
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // check for an exception first
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (e.Result != null)
            {
                splitPanelLeftRight.Panel2.Controls.Add((UserControl)e.Result);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingWrapper.Logger.LogException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show how you are changing the control?

Comment: Though .NET simplifies memory management by automatic garbage collection, it can't avoid memory leaks. Please, show us some fragments of your code, especially database access.

Comment: Are you removing the prior UserControl from the pane, or just adding new ones on top.  You have to remove the olds ones at some point.

Comment: How do you measure memory use?  And does it really grow to become a problem?

Comment: If you don't `.Dispose()` of the control you are replacing, it will continue to exist in memory until the garbage collector catches up with it. Eventually it will be destroyed, but until then the memory remains in use. The same goes for other resources that implement IDisposable.

Comment: @JamieSee - calling Dispose() does not release or free any memory.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, Actually that isn't necessarily true. One of the primary uses of the IDisposable pattern is to clean up unmanaged resources. This usually results in memory being freed, in addition to other things like locks on files, etc. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx. If you don't call `.Dispose()` yourself, the garbage collector will **eventually** do it on your behalf, but until then those unmanaged resources hang out. It's best to be in the habit of disposing your disposable objects.

Comment: Added code fragment.  I know it seems overly complex, but it needs to be for various reasons.